# How to remove the Horizontal Scrollbar for Jquery Splitter Plugin

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling, splitter

I'm using this splitter for an app... http://methvin.com/splitter/

What i need is to remove de horizontal scrollbar, I need to always display the full list on screen. Yet, i do need to keep the vertical one...

any ideas how?

Answer (score 0):

Try the "overflow-x: hidden". Take a look at this link http://www.brunildo.org/test/Overflowxy.html.

Comment: this only hides the overflow of the x axis... that's not what i'm looking for. Maybe something that will expand the control's height until it covers the whole area?